# Intersection Observer React Why is my code not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, intersection-observer

I want to make an "Intersection Observer" for my project that I created with React. From what I've researched on the internet, I think I followed all the instructions correctly. But my code doesn't work, I don't understand where is the error. Can you help me please ?

My react project code;

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header'
import HeroImage from './components/HeroImage'
import Hakkimizda from './components/Hakkimizda'
import UrunGalerisi from './components/UrunGalerisi'
import Sss from './components/sss'
import Footer from './components/Footer'
import { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';



function App() {


      //Variables
      const containerRef = useRef(null);
      const [isVisible, setIsvisible] = useState(false);
    
      //callbackFunction
      const callBackFunction = (entries)=>{
        const [entry] = entries;
        setIsvisible(entry.isIntersecting);
      }
      //Options
      const options = { 
        root:'null',
        rootMargin:'0px',
        treshold:1.0
      }
    
      //useEffect
      useEffect(()=>{
      const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callBackFunction, options)
      if(containerRef.current) observer.observe(containerRef.current)
          return ()=>{ if(containerRef.current) observer.unobserve(containerRef.current) }
      }, [containerRef, options])
    
  return (
    <div className="App">
         <Header />
          <HeroImage  />
          <Hakkimizda  />
          <UrunGalerisi />
          <Sss />
          <Footer  />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

the error I get is;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTYHi.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach the `containerRef` to the DOM element you want to observe, with something like :

```
<div ref={containerRef}>foo</div>
```

Comment: I added like this but nothing changed;

```
  return (
    <div ref={containerRef} className="App">
         <Header />
          <HeroImage  />
          <Hakkimizda  />
          <UrunGalerisi />
          <Sss />
          <Footer  />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App; 
```

Comment: You're also not importing React : `import React from "react'`

Comment: I did that too but the error persists :(

Comment: @Sr.Developer please, add minimal reproduce to some platform like https://codesandbox.io/

Answer (score 0):

@krirkrirk

I added like this but nothing changed;

```
  return (
    <div ref={containerRef} className="App">
         <Header />
          <HeroImage  />
          <Hakkimizda  />
          <UrunGalerisi />
          <Sss />
          <Footer  />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```